# How to access two 2007 fields from two difference sources for each loan

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables, one of them is MI_Export and the other one is NY_DIR. Both of them have a Loan_Number field. NY_DIR table has "MTM LTV" field and MI_Export table has a "LTV_Final" field. Those two fields are supposed to be similar or same for the most part, but since they are calculated by two different parties, there are expected discrepancies. I would like to create a query to find the discrepancies in LTV values between two tables based on the loan numbers. I am not very good with access yet, so if you could help me, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That could be:

```
Select 
    MI_Export.*,
    NY_DIR.*
From
    MI_Export,
    NY_DIR
Where
    MI_Export.Loan_Number = NY_DIR.Loan_Number 
    And
    MI_Export.LTV_Final <> NY_DIR.MTM LTV
```